# qml image not being reloaded/refreshed error

Tags: c++, image, qml, qt5, reload

Whenever 'videoUpdate' function in main.qml is called, 'line H'(in MainGUI.qml) executes and requestImage(in ImageProvider.cpp) returns a QImage object. However, the image returned doesn't appear on the MainGUI (video)Image. (Right after the program executes, only once, apple image appears and stays there forever.)
Did I do something wrong?

***Important(maybe): compiler used is "catkin_make"(for ROS project) which calls cmake instead of "qmake followed by make" which is the default compilation steps in "Qt Creator"(qt5).**

### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 460
    property alias mainForm: mainForm
    property int videoWidth: 314
    property int videoHeight: 236

    property int imageSN : 0
    function videoUpdate() {
        imageSN++;
        mainForm.videoTube.source = "image://images/" + imageSN
        console.log("video frame ID#: " + imageSN)
        return ""
    }

    MainGUI {
        id: mainForm
        objectName: "mainForm"
        anchors.fill: parent

        signal startSignal()
        signal stopSignal()

        mouseArea_start.onClicked: {
            mainForm.startSignal();
        }

        mouseArea_stop.onClicked: {
            mainForm.stopSignal();
        }

        mouseArea_quit.onClicked: {
            mainForm.stopSignal();
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

### MainGUI.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Rectangle {
    id: mainRect
    property alias mouseArea_quit: mouseArea_quit
    property alias mouseArea_start: mouseArea_start
    property alias mouseArea_stop: mouseArea_stop
    property alias videoTube: videoTube

    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle {
        id: rect_start
        x: 40
        y: 27
        width: 132
        height: 56
        color: "#ffffff"
        radius: 10
        border.width: 5

        Text {
            id: text1
            x: 0
            y: 21
            width: 132
            height: 15
            color: "#0f650d"
            text: qsTr("시작")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter

            font.bold: true
            font.pixelSize: 16
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea_start
            objectName: "mouseArea_start"

            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 132
            height: 56
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect_stop
        x: 190
        y: 27
        width: 132
        height: 56
        color: "#ffffff"
        radius: 10
        border.width: 5

        Text {
            id: text2
            x: 9
            y: 20
            width: 110
            height: 15
            color: "#ff0000"
            text: qsTr("멈춤")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.bold: true
            font.pixelSize: 16
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea_stop
            objectName: "mouseArea_stop"
            x: 10
            y: 0
            width: 110
            height: 56
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect_quit
        x: 167
        y: 379
        width: 162
        height: 55
        color: "#ffffff"

        Text {
            x: 30
            y: 18
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Quit Program"
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 12
            anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 0
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 0
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea_quit
            x: 0
            y: 0
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: videoTube
        objectName: "videoTube"
        width: videoWidth
        height: videoHeight
        anchors.rightMargin: 20
        anchors.leftMargin: 20
        anchors.bottomMargin: 30
        anchors.top: rect_start.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: rect_quit.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.topMargin: 30
        source : "image://images/" + imageSN
        onSourceChanged: {
            console.log("source changed") // line H
        }
        cache: false
        sourceSize.width: videoWidth
        sourceSize.height: videoHeight
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }

    Image {
        id: sm_img
        x: 20
        y: 357
        width: 100
        height: 100

    }
}
```

### ImageProvider.cpp

```
#include "ImageProvider.h"
#include <QDebug>

ImageProvider::ImageProvider(QSize size)
    : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image)
{
    apple = new QImage();
    pear = new QImage();

    if (apple->load("apple.jpg")) {
    } else {
        qDebug() << "apple loading failed";
    }

    if (pear->load("pear.jpg")) {
    } else {
        qDebug() << "pear loading failed";
    }

    currentShot = new QImage();
    if (currentShot->load("echo.png")) {
        QImage *temp = currentShot;
        currentShot = new QImage(currentShot->scaled(
                                     size, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
        delete temp;
    } else {
        delete currentShot;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief ImageProvider::requestImage
 * @param id : unique ID, generated in qml code (specify image to fecth)
 *             In case of WMPC, this parameter is needless.
 *              -- jbpark03@gmail.com
 * @param size : new image size if applicable
 * @param requestedSize : desired size; if valid, resize original and
 *                        return resized version and modify 3rd size para'.
 * @return
 */
QImage ImageProvider::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size,
                                   const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    if (id.toInt() % 3 == 0) {
        *size = apple->size();
        return *apple;
    } else if (id.toInt() % 3 != 0) {
        *size = pear->size();
        return *pear;
    }

    if (requestedSize.isValid() &&
            sizeDiffers(requestedSize, currentShot->size()))
    {
        QImage * modifiedImg =
                new QImage(currentShot->scaled(requestedSize, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));

        delete currentShot;
        currentShot = nullptr;

        *size = modifiedImg->size();
        return *modifiedImg;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "invalid or size matched";

        // do nothing: just return currentShot
        QImage *temp = currentShot;
        *size = currentShot->size();

        QImage temp2 = QImage(*currentShot).convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB32);
        qDebug() << "return size: " << temp2.size() << ", type: "
                 << temp2.format() << "\n";
        temp2.save("echo.png");
        *size = temp2.size();
        return temp2;
    }
}

bool ImageProvider::sizeDiffers(QSize ltSize, QSize rtSize)
{
    if (std::abs(ltSize.width() - rtSize.width()) > 1 ||
            std::abs(ltSize.height() - rtSize.height()) > 1)
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qml Image not updated after requestImage returns QImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126471/qml-image-not-updated-after-requestimage-returns-qimage)

Comment: I can't retract my close vote, even though http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes says I can. :/ Anyway, you're not likely to get answers until you narrow down your problem to something that we can compile and run ourselves. If there's "too much code", then you haven't tried hard enough to narrow it down. :p

Comment: I uploaded whole contents(except debugging purpose codes) of 3 related files included in the original question above.

Comment: One more thing to mention: I compiled this program using catkin_make with the help of CMakeLists.txt (the other option was qmake followed by make) in the "qt creator(qt5)" IDE environment.